# How to rename multiple files at once and replace specific characters without affecting other characters

Tags: powershell, file-rename

I want to replace the first two numbers on these 98 files that looks like this

```
10 10HZ.mp3
11 11HZ.mp3
12 12HZ.mp3
```

with "Bass Mekanik - " and make it look like this

```
Bass Mekanik - 10HZ.mp3
Bass Mekanik - 11HZ.mp3
Bass Mekanik - 12HZ.mp3
```

I've tried a lot of different combinations on CMD like this

*rename "?? ????.mp3" "Bass Mekanik - ????.mp3"

But nothing works. I want to keep the last 4 characters on every file.

Also in the near future I will need to add "Bass Mekanik - " in front of every file (not on these files, other files that have a lot of other characters) without changing anything else. So far I learned how to remove the first 2 characters using

*rename "?? ????.mp3" "// ????.mp3"

Then I tried adding "Bass Mekanik" but it gives an error "A duplicate file name exists, or the file
cannot be found."
I hope this is possible ...

Comment: [1] save the .Extension to $Ext [2] save the `.BaseName` to `$BaseName` [3] trim away the unwanted parts of `$BaseName` [4] add the new parts to the remaining `$BaseName` [5] add the `$BaseName` & `$Ext` to make a `$NewFileName` [6] use that to rename the file. [grin]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you need, remove the WhatIf's if you're happy with the results

Keep last 4 (8 with ".mp3") characters of filename and prefix with "Bass Mekanik "

```
Get-ChildItem | % { $_.FullName -match ".{8}(?<=\.mp3$)" | Out-Null ; Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName ( "Bass Mekanik " + $Matches.Values ) -WhatIf }
```

Prefix current filename with "Bass Mekanik "

```
Get-ChildItem | % { Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName ("Bass Mekanik" + $_.Name ) -WhatIf }
```

Comment: Yes! The first one works! Thank you so much for your time! <3